# extract only text or image from blob (php mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I have BLOB field in MySql table with text and image inside, is there any way to extract out only text or only images?

```
  $query  = "SELECT id, date, blob, FROM table ORDER BY id  DESC ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))         {
    echo 

"<div class=all>
   "<ul class=id>{$row['id']}</ul>".
   "<ul class=date>{$row['date']}</ul>" .
  "<ul class=blob_image><IMAGE>{$row['blob']}</IMAGE></ul>".
  "<ul class=blob_text><TEXT>{$row['blob']}</TEXT></ul>
 </div>";
} 

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Thank you

Comment: this is not very clear in the text or image stuff that are in the blob, shouldn't there be something that identifies the blob content (for example mimetype ),However using Blob to store files is considered as bad BD practice as DB server are inefficient with blob when compared to the filesystem.

Comment: its not an file inside, its parsed atom feed inside, with image, text, embed link.....

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is: You could analyze a blob's content and decide whether you are handling text or an image. For this purpose, you have to be clear about the encoding of the text as well as the format of the images to distinguish between them accurately. To be even more accurate, I could analyze the characters of possible text and reject the "text case" if "invalid" characters are included (dependent on the semantics and context which requires background knowledge).